# faster-than-requests installing error python

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, python-module

Hey am trying to install faster-than-requests with and from file directly non of them works it gives an error : 
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> pip install faster-than-requests
Collecting faster-than-requests
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/90/15/72ffe29bf34b40b4b9881a89e0fbbf9d22ea0b493681965fd08ce1fafa7b/faster_than_requests-0.9.2.zip
Installing collected packages: faster-than-requests
  Running setup.py install for faster-than-requests ... error
    Complete output from command c:\users\gaming\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='C:\Users\GAMING\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-g86h8jtt\faster-than-requests\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\GAMING\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-8b_4dut4\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    running build_ext
    building 'faster_than_requests' extension
    error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/

```
----------------------------------------
```

Command "c:\users\gaming\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='C:\Users\GAMING\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-g86h8jtt\faster-than-requests\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\GAMING\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-8b_4dut4\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\GAMING\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-g86h8jtt\faster-than-requests\